# Can a 11-speed derailleur be used with a 9-speed shifter?

Tags: shimano, shifter, derailleur-rear, shifting

Can a 11-speed derailleur be used with a 9-speed shifter
I want to buy a 11-speed derailleur and have  a 9-speed shifter so will they work together or not?

Comment: Are you talking about road or MTB, Shimano or SRAM? What do you have? Some combinations *might* produce acceptable results (in theory).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you plan on upgrading shifters and drive train at some point? As Klaster said some would work in theory, but it would not be optimal performance

Comment: The derailer has no idea how many "speeds" it supports, since it does not contain any sort of indexing mechanism -- it simply moves X distance for Y cable movement.  (Plus, the angle of movement must roughly suit the angle described by adjacent cogs in the cluster.)  What's important is the X/Y ratio, and that's a function of the individual manufacturer's design for that specific set of derailer and shifter.  There used to be standards of a sort, but anymore you need to look up each component if you're mismatching between "lines", even for a given manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

With Shimano, no. The cable pulls are different. You might be able to futz with a JTek Shiftmate to get something working, but the cost would be way higher than just buying a 7-9 speed rear derailleur.

Comment: Chain width won't matter?

Comment: I think you can make it work, but not optimally. The real answer is that buying a 7-9 speed derailleur and a 11 speed derailleur will probably be cheaper than buying a 11 speed derailleur and the extra stuff you need to get it to work suboptimally.

Answer (score 2):

A friction shifter won't care. I'm using a 5-speed vintage stem shifter with a 9 speed cassette.

But indexed shifters unfortunately have to be matched to the same number derailleur and cassette.

Answer (score 0):

With Campagnolo, yes. From 9 to 11 speeds, cable pull is the same.

Of course, this is assuming that you have a Campagnolo shifter. If you don't know the brand, you are out of luck.

Comment: Question is tagged Shimano so I'd think it wasn't Campy.